# post data to payment gateway by redirecting from controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, payment-gateway, payumoney

I am trying to hit payumoney Payment Gateway url from my controller function. The data that needs to be passed to payment gateway url, is available in variables/array. How can I user header or redirect function along with data posted so that the target url of payment gateway can capture it and process?

Flow of my code: On clicking checkout button, I create a transaction in database, and calls the following controller function. This function should open the payment page which will create the order from cart on successful payment. So, I need to call the payment gateway url from this controller, I cannot load any view here to create a form for submission.
Here is my controller code:

```
$host = "https://sandboxsecure.payu.in";
$path = "/_payment";
//$posted has some data in the form of array
$data=http_build_query($posted);
//$data=urlencode($data);
header("POST $path HTTP/1.1");
header("Host: $host");
header("Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
header("Content-length: " . strlen($data));
header($data);
```

This code downloads a raw file which is blank instead of redirecting to the target url.

Comment: Are you sure you are expected to have the user post the transaction data to the gateway? That is MASSIVELY insecure. The most logical and secure way would be: your site posts the transaction payload to the gateway, gets an initial response and probably a transaction token or something similar and then (and only then) you redirect the user to the payment gateway. Two separate steps. Your code allows the user to carry the transaction information with him, which allows such data to be tampered with. I doubt PayU works that way

Comment: I side with @JavierLarroulet but you may try sending a `Location` header to redirect. Also, once you redirect, all the header information would be gone as data is not preserved across redirects. It would be better to do a POST via cURL

Comment: @JavierLarroulet In the samples provided by payumoney, they have a form which has a list of products and within that form they want us to maintain the hash. But in my application, I am integrating 2 payment gateways. So, I cannot put my cart or checkout page in the payment gateway. I have 2 options, COD & Online. If user selects Onilne and submits, a transaction is created and the same needs to take user to the payment page where user will fill card details. Now, in the sample of payumoney, they expect the information to be passed to them while landing on the payment method fill page.

Comment: @ShammiShailaj I tried hitting the payumoney payment page with CURL but it returns a complete web page and gives a JS error. Looks like I have to redirect from my controller to their payment page where user will fill card details and transact

Comment: @ITSagar Do it from the client side then.

Comment: @ShammiShailaj You mean I should create a form dynamically and hit it using jquery?

Comment: Yes. something on those lines.